# Passport Strength (with stamps and visas)

Tags: passports, passport-stamps

Websites listing the "strength" of passports of each country are nothing new - it's relatively easy to find information what countries one can visit without the need for a visa (and in case of my country, the ministry of foreign affairs lists visa requirements for each foreign territory).

But is there any website when I can see how much my passport strength has been inflicted by different stamps that have been put in it?

For example, I have a stamp from Israel-Jordan border crossing, which proves that I've been in Israel, effectively banning me from a few Arab countries. I'm also planning to visit Armenia and their stamp would ban me from Azerbaijan.

Again, it's not hard to find this information for individual countries - but is there any comprehensive source that lists them all?

Comment: An Armenian stamp does not prohibit you from entering Azerbaijan. Evidence of a trip to Artsakh would do that.

Comment: It is difficult. I do not have stamps from Israel-Jordan border. You may get two passports (common in case of trade with Arabic and Israel, but also one old [with some stamps] and a new). The list changes often (see US with some countries), and sometime traveling in X just requires a visa for Y.

Comment: @Richard: Good to know. Did something change or was I misinformed all the time?

Comment: @user1234567 I don't believe it was ever the case that visiting Armenia itself precluded one from visiting Azerbaijan. Azerbaijan does ban Armenians and people of Armenian descent, though (with some exceptions such as Arsenal footballer Henrikh Mkhitaryan, even if he did not take them up on their offer). But do expect any Armenian stamps to prompt questions when entering Azerbaijan.

Comment: Even if there were it would be just nonsense because there are thousands of  permutations. Would serve no purpose and a waste of time to try to quantify such.